# Definition of G-crossed complex.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I was reading about crossed complexes following R.Brown. I was wondering how one define G-crossed complexes for a topological group G? Is it just dimension wise action of the group?

Answer (score 2):

There are papers on equivariant crossed complexes, see [93,114] on my [publication  list](http://groupoids.org.uk/publicfull.htm), where the second deals with the topological group case.

A second possibly related question is to deal with Galois cohomology, using crossed complex methods. There are papers of M.V.Borovoi on nonabelian Galois cohomology with coefficients  in a crossed module.

Comment: Thanks for the references. Is it possible for you to write the definition here?